# Video/Animated GIF advanced frame editor?

Tags: video-editing, animation, gif

What sort of application could I use for example if I had a 5 minute video or an animated GIF with 50 frames, and I wanted to basically Photoshop replace an object, say a person's head, with another image for all those 50 frames? Is there some sort of smart tool that can do this or do I have to edit every single frame by hand?

I wouldn't mind there being a tool where I can paste the image in every frame automatically, and switch from frame to frame adjusting the position of it, I just need something efficient.

I've tried using Photoshop's import video into image sequence and tried editing with the animation toolbar at the bottom, but it's not quite what I want. I don't care if it's free software or not, I'm primarily using Linux but I have VirtualBox Windows XP if there's an excellent application that's not available otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

Use GIMP with GAP installed. It's free, open source, and runs on just about anything.

http://www.gimp.org/downloads

Comment: Hi, I use GIMP withou installing any thing else and can edit the .gif file :)

Comment: @NamGVU My understanding is that GAP offers facilities to manipulate animated Gifs, like easy navigation, special effects, etc. Problem, it lags behind Gimp, and GAP 2.6 doesn't work well with Gimp 2.8 on Windows (for me, at least). But indeed, Gimp alone can open a Gif as a layered image with timing for each of them, and save it back as animated Gif.

Answer (score 2):

[Ulead GIF Animator](http://www.ulead.com/ga/) can do this easily. You will need to reposition the head for each frame though.

[image]