# Is there an app I can use to edit an existing animated GIF?

Tags: gif

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Video/Animated GIF advanced frame editor?](https://superuser.com/questions/83684/video-animated-gif-advanced-frame-editor)

I’ve found a fair few apps that create animated GIFs from a series of existing images.

Are there any apps that can take an existing animated GIF, and allow me to edit it? I specifically want to edit every frame in an existing animated GIF.

I’ve tried opening the GIF in question in Photoshop CS4 on Windows, but its animation palette only shows me one frame.

Either Mac or Windows would be good.

Comment: @ChrisF: I haven’t seen one that lets me edit individual frames. Have you?

Comment: He understands that, but the trick is to get one that can extract the pictures within the gif, which is no easy trick. A lot about that out there. He wants a solution that is all-in-one.

Comment: I'm still amazed that there isn't a single Adobe CS product that supports this yet.  It's not exactly a cutting-edge file format...!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes, [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) can handle animated GIFs by bringing each frame into a separate layer.

Comment: Tick the "As animation" checkbox when you get the "Export Image as GIF" dialog up after clicking the "Export" button.      
(This took me a little while to figure out which is why I'm mentioning it here)

Comment: This works, but GIMP is very clunky for editing animated GIFs. You want something that can flip between frames, maintain the transparent pixels from previous frames (as GIFs are meant to be viewed), and not have to manually hide and unhide layers all the time.  Honestly, the best thing I have for editing animated GIFs is... Jasc Animation Shop 3.11, from way back in the day.  Still works, even with quite large animated GIFs from LICEcap.  Not sure you can buy it anymore though!