# How can I edit the delay of the first frame of an animated gif

Tags: linux, gif, gnuplot, animated-gif

I've assembled a gif using gnuplot, however I want the first frame to be still for a few seconds before the graphic starts animating. How can I edit the delay of the first frame of the gif?

Comment: Get an animated GIF editor: http://superuser.com/questions/308152/is-there-an-app-i-can-use-to-edit-an-existing-animated-gif?rq=1, http://superuser.com/questions/83684/video-animated-gif-advanced-frame-editor

Comment: Did you try to write directly in the script something similar to `set terminal gif animate delay 100` after `set output 'img.gif'` and then `plot datafile.dat  ...` ? with the data of each single frame separated by an empty line? let me know if it works